Error creating deployment package for AWS Lambda R script
I'm trying to deploy an R script to AWS Lambda. The script is in file handler.R. I created a bootstrap file:
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail
EVENT_DATA=$(cat /dev/stdin)
Rscript /var/task/handler.R "$EVENT_DATA"

and a Dockerfile:
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.5

RUN R -e "install.packages('jsonlite', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY handler.R .
COPY bootstrap .
RUN chmod +x bootstrap
ENTRYPOINT ["./bootstrap"]

Then I built the image:
docker build -t my-r-image .

I verified the files are in the proper location and bootstrap is executable:
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh my-r-image
ls -l /var/task

and I get
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 166 Jul  4 08:45 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 267 Jul  4 07:50 handler.R

Then I try to create the deployment package:
mkdir dist
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}/dist:/var/task" my-r-image sh -c "cp /var/task/bootstrap /var/task/handler.R /var/task/dist/"

but I get the following error:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./bootstrap": stat ./bootstrap: no such file or directory: unknown.


Is it possible that the shim task is setting a different workdir? Try using an absolute path in the entry point, and verify inside the entrypoint script that the path is set as expected.

I edited the Dockerfile as ENTRYPOINT ["/var/task/bootstrap"], but I still get the same error. It can't find the script even with an absolute path...

Ah, right, I overlooked your docker run invocation. You are overwriting /var/task inside your container with your volume mount. Of course it now contains the contents of the dist subdirectory outside your container.

So I have to change the volume mount with "${PWD}/dist:/var/task/dist" to mount only the dist subdirectory? Sorry if my question is trivial, but I'm still learning how docker works.

Yup, that would work.

I changed as docker run --rm -v "${PWD}/dist:/var/task/dist" my-r-image sh -c "cp /var/task/bootstrap /var/task/handler.R /var/task/dist/"but I get exec /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory.
